# How to create custom constraints for Firebase Job dispatcher?

Tags: android, constraints, firebase-job-dispatcher

I need to do a job when the device is charging and if the battery is full or almost full.

It's a very demanding job, it will eventually run, but I don't want to risk doing it when my user has just put the device to a quick charge when battery is low.